# Android RSS reader app SQLite DB schema

Tags: android, sqlite, rss

this is my first question so I hope I wont mess anything :)

I'm working on an assignment for my university class. I'm implementing Android RSS reader app. All the parsing and UI code is done but I have some problems with SQLite DB schema. I need to store two data sets - blogs that user subscribes and posts for each blog.

Blog dataset contains: blogTitle, blogUrl and rssUrl

Post dataset contains: postTitle, postUrl, postPublicationDate and two booleans (isRead and isFavourite)

1. There is list of all posts (sorted by postPublicationDate)
2. There is separate list of all favourite posts
3. User is able to set post as fav or "un fav" it (from both lists)
4. After reading post (opening it in separate Activity) post is marked as "read" - with different color on the list - after user leaves app and goes back after some time read posts are not shown (or removed from db - not sure which way is better to implement it)
5. Posts set as "favourite" are shown in "favourite posts" list even when already read (so they are stored permanently for as long as user removes them manually)
6. I think it would be wise to limit number of posts stored for each blog (again, not sure if it's necessary) and remove oldest posts (lets say the limit will be 40)
7. There is "blogs" list which shows all subscribed blogs (with number of unread items)

I implemented it already but I think my implementation is a little bit "hacky". All the functionality above is my own design so feel free to point out some newbie mistakes (I'm not very experienced with databases and programming in general). I hope someone will help, cause I have short deadline for this assignment... :)

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Sorry :) Question: how to implement SQLite db schema to best suit this kind of app/functionality?